# CSS Positioning and Overlapping

Tags: html, css, overlay, positioning

I have a CSS generated section of an HTML page.  It is currently positioned to be in the main content region of the page, which is right of a navigation bar.  I have a graph that needs to be centered to the whole HTML page, which includes being under the navigation bar.

How would I use CSS positioning to overlay a block of HTML code (which has some CSS too) to be centered over the whole page.

I have a hunch as to how to do this:
I think that I need overlapping CSS section to go under the navigation bar.

```
.layout #mainContent  h6 {
position:absolute;
left:-1000px;
top:-10px;
z-index:5
}
```

The HTML to be overlayed will go under h6.

The HTML will be written like this

```
<h6>
    All the HTML code to be overlaid
</h6>
```

I more or less want a way to center all the code in a section of my html, but it has to be centered relative to the whole HTML page, not just the CSS boxed section.

Comment: `<h8>` isn't a valid HTML tag. The header tags go up to `<h6>`. Also, can you reword your question? It's not really too clear what you're asking.

Comment: We need more details on the code ... give us the other element that you want to be overlapped

Comment: I changed it to <h6>.  This question is probably too wordy, but I just need to center some HTML in the center of the whole page, not just a CSS box.  So I would love to just <center> but of course it just puts in in the center of the CSS box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting a fixed width and height to the overlay content. eg:

```
.layout #mainContent h6 {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top:-10px;   /* half element's height */
    margin-left:-100px; /* half element's width */
    z-index:1000
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P95Bz/1/

Comment: thank you, that works quit well, but is there any way to apply this to a whole block html code or just wherever there is the heading?

Comment: to apply this to a whole block of code, use a div rather than an h6 for the overlay content

Answer (score 1):

We centre things often using css and this is how we'd do it:

```
.layout #mainContent h6 {
position:absolute;
left:50%; 
margin-left:-1000px; /* half the element's width */
top:50%;
margin-top:-10px; /* half the element's height */
z-index:5
}
```

But of course to centre the height in all browsers & screen resolutions you have to add the following conditions to **body** tag, otherwise the browser will assume the body is only as high as it's content (ie. 20px in your case).

```
body {
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100% !important;
  width:100%;
}
```